# Запись данных из датафрейма pyspark в другую таблицу cassandra по id

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra

Такой вопрос, предположим есть таблица в cassandra **test**:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | country | counter |
+====+=========+=========+
|  A |      RU |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  B |      EN |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  C |      IQ |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  D |      RU |       3 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Так же есть таблица в том же пространстве **main** в которой пару десятков столбцов и есть столбец аналогичный country, назовем его country_main и аналогичный id - main_id.

В столбце main_id есть как айдишники из таблицы test, так и уникальные айдишники. В столбце country есть пустые ячейки. Примерно так:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+
| main_id | country_main |      ...|
+=========+==============+=========+
|  A      |              |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
|  B      |      EN      |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
|  Y      |      IQ      |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
|  Z      |      RU      |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
```

Каким образом средствами pyspark сделать инсерт данных из таблицы test в main,  что бы заполнить пустые ячейки таблицы main согласно айдишникам из теста?

Comment: только пустые ячейки?

Comment: @AlexOtt да, заполнить пустые, а там где значение есть не изменять.

Comment: ответил на StackOverflow...